# Polymer UI with Spring Rest API - authentication issue

Tags: ajax, spring, authentication, polymer, jsessionid

I'm trying to secure access to some REST APIs using form-based authentication against LDAP. This part is actually working fine: - I enter user and password in the form provided by the default page at http://localhost:1304/login and then I can access all other APIs: http://localhost:1304/user or http://localhost:1304/api/v1/search/draft.

The problem is I'm trying to use APIs such as http://localhost:1304/api/v1/search/draft from a Polymer frontend started separately on a node server on localhost:8081. I managed to get rid of all CORS issues so I don't think it's about these. I'm using an ajax-form to post username&password&submit and I can see in the spring app log that the authentication is successful. However, when my UI is trying to do a GET on that /api/v1/search/draft API it fails and the call is redirect under the hood to /login (or return a 401 when I'm using a custom authenticationEntryPoint). But if I'm logging in using http://localhost:1304/login then my UI page is able to do the APIs GETs.

In spring I have:

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login", "/","/src/**","/bower_components/**", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/logout", "/oauth/revoke-token","/oauth/check_token").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()                                    
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .rememberMe()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    ; }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8081"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        //configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

The /api/v1/search/draft is called with an iron-ajax:

```
<iron-ajax id="get_drafts"  handle-as="json" last-response="{{drafts}}" on-response="_onDraftsResponse" debounce-duration="900" with-credentials="true"></iron-ajax>
```

For the authentication with my polymer UI the headers are like this:

```
**GENERAL**
Request URL:http://localhost:1304/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 
Remote Address:[::1]:1304
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8081
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 20 Jan 2018 11:43:25 GMT
Expires:0
Location:http://localhost:1304/
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=DBCAF4C1FD5D1C1655EFF873B6D556EE; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary:Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
**Request Headers**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:96
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:1304
Origin:http://localhost:8081
Referer:http://localhost:8081/overview
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

subsequent API calls to /draft using different sessionID in the request header

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=309D6615798B57247756C33808D57559
```

For authentication using default /login form I have:

```
**GENERAL**
Request URL:http://localhost:1304/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 
Remote Address:[::1]:1304
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
**Response Headers**
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 20 Jan 2018 11:47:30 GMT
Expires:0
Location:http://localhost:1304/
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=330CDE874819AA32E134A41EFB21B8E1; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
**Request Headers**

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=309D6615798B57247756C33808D57559
Host:localhost:1304
Origin:http://localhost:1304
Referer:http://localhost:1304/login?logout
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

all other calls using from now on the new

```
JSESSIONID=330CDE874819AA32E134A41EFB21B8E1
```

I feel I'm really close to the solution. What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the ajax-form I was using. Changing to a simple form solved the authentication problem but now from localhost:8081 (where is the UI) I'm redirected to localhost:1304 (where the login API was called from). I guess I need to go to spring code to solve this.